# Rule chain matrix by vector

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, derivatives, vectors

Let $\boldsymbol{X}$ be a $n \times p$ matrix and $\boldsymbol{\beta}$ a $p-$dimensional vector. I'd like to calculate

$$
\frac{\partial f(\boldsymbol{X\beta})}{\partial\boldsymbol{\beta}}
$$

I tried

$$
f'(\boldsymbol{X\beta}) \boldsymbol{X}
$$

but, obviously, the dimensions are not correct.

Comment: why is the codomain of $f$? Your expression seems right if $f$ is a functional

Comment: Real greater than zero.

Comment: My CAS says $$ \boldsymbol{X} f'(\boldsymbol{X} \boldsymbol{\beta})$$ So you had it almost, except for the pre-multiplying part.

Comment: @ja72 it depends how you understand matrix multiplication. If matrix multiplication is understood as $vM$, here $v$ is a vector and $M$ a matrix, then your result follows. However it is more common to have matrix multiplication as $Mv$, then my result follow. In general, not using matrix representation, the correct answer is $\partial f(X\beta)X$ because chain rule is defined from left to right, because after all is just a composition of functions, what CAS had you used?

Comment: I disagree, since in my notation it is always matrix-vector. $\boldsymbol{f}$ and $\boldsymbol{f'}$ are vector functions and $\boldsymbol{X}$ is a matrix. Where is the chain rule defined left ot right? Why is $(f(g(x)))' = g'(x)\,f'(g(x))$ incorrect?

Comment: @ja72 I explained in my previous comment. To make it more clear to you took a book of multivariable calculus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take an ordinary *scalar* function $\phi(z)$ and its derivative
$\phi'(z)=\frac{d\phi}{dz}$ and apply them element-wise to a vector argument, i.e. 
$$\eqalign{
v &= X\beta,\quad
f &= \phi(v),\quad
f' &= \phi'(v) \cr
}$$
The differential of such a *vector* function can be expressed using an elementwise $(\odot)$ product or better yet, a Diagonal matrix 
$$\eqalign{
df &= f'\odot  dv \cr
 &= {\rm Diag}(f')\,dv \cr
 &= {\rm Diag}(f')\,X\,d\beta \cr
}$$
Given this differential, the gradient with respect to $\beta$ can be identified as the *matrix*
$$\eqalign{
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \beta} &= {\rm Diag}(f')X \cr\cr
}$$
An example of the equivalence of Hadamard product and diagonalization:
$$\eqalign{
&a = \pmatrix{a_1\\a_2},\quad
&b = \pmatrix{b_1\\b_2},\quad
&a&\odot&b = \pmatrix{a_1b_1\\a_2b_2} = b\odot a \cr
&A = {\rm Diag}(a) = &\pmatrix{a_1&0\\0&a_2},\quad
&&A&b = \pmatrix{a_1b_1\\a_2b_2} \cr
&B = {\rm Diag}(b) = &\pmatrix{b_1&0\\0&b_2},\quad
&&B&a = \pmatrix{a_1b_1\\a_2b_2} \cr
}$$

Comment: I'm not mathematician, can you help me with the elementwise product? Specifically $df = f' \odot dv$. Why can we transform in $diag(f')$.

Answer (score 1):

You have that, as you wrote

$$\partial[f(X\beta)]=\partial f(X\beta) X$$

for $f:\Bbb R^n\to[0,\infty)$ and $X:\Bbb R^p\to\Bbb R^n$. Then $\partial f(X\beta)$ can be represented by the gradient $\nabla f(X\beta)$, that it is a vector on $\Bbb R^n$ and $\nabla f(X\beta)X$ is a vector on $\Bbb R^p$, that is the gradient of $f\circ X$ in $\beta$, hence

$$\partial f(X\beta) Xh=\nabla f(X\beta)X\cdot h=\nabla(f\circ X)(\beta)\cdot h$$

for any $h\in\Bbb R^p$, where the dot is the euclidean dot product.