# Product rule for matrix derivative

Tags: matrix-calculus

For $\nabla_X Y(X) = \nabla_X U(X)V(X)$, is there a general formula to differentiate it? I guess it is something like $\left(\frac{\partial U}{\partial X}\right)^T V(X) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial X} U(X)^T$ (denominator layout). However, when I was trying to derive it with chain rule, I get:

$\begin{align*}
\frac{\partial Y}{\partial X} &= \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial U} + \frac{\partial V}{\partial X} \frac{\partial Y}{\partial V} \\
&= \frac{\partial U}{\partial X} V(X) + \frac{\partial V}{\partial X} U(X)^T 
\end{align*}$

which obvious doesn't even produce correct dimensions for matrix multiplication.
What is the proper way to differentiate it (in denominator layout)?

Comment: take a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223312/rule-chain-matrix-by-vector), maybe it helps. What are $U, V$ and $X$ in your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A matrix-by-matrix gradient results in a fourth-order tensor. To handle such calculations within matrix calculus, you must use vectorization.
$$\eqalign{
&u={\rm vec}(U),\quad v={\rm vec}(V),\quad x={\rm vec}(X),\quad y={\rm vec}(Y) \cr
&{\rm vec}(AYB) = (B^T\otimes A)\,y \cr
}$$
Start by calculating the differential of $Y$, then substitute the known gradients of $U$ and $V$.
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= UV \cr
dY &= U\,dV + dU\,V \cr
 &= U\,dV\,I_v + I_u\,dU\,V \cr
dy &= (I_v^T\otimes U)\,dv + (V^T\otimes I_u)\,du \cr
\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}
 &= \Big(I_v\otimes U\Big)\,\frac{\partial v}{\partial x}
  + \Big(V^T\otimes I_u\Big)\,\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \cr
}$$
where the $I_k$ are identity matrices of appropriate dimension.

Comment: Greg, can you recommend a book on this subject?

Comment: The standard text is probably  _Matrix Differential Calculus_ by Magnus and Neudecker.

Comment: @greg The book is really good, thanks for recommendation